# Expo: 'react-native-wifi-reborn' lib is not working

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I use `react-native-wifi-reborn` in my react-native application (expo);
App is configured according to [official docs](https://github.com/JuanSeBestia/react-native-wifi-reborn#readme)

I need to connect to a specified wifi network with predifined ssid and password.

```
import WifiManager from 'react-native-wifi-reborn';

const onClickConnect = async (ssid: string) => {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
      {
        title: 'Location permission is required for WiFi connections',
        message:
          'This app needs location permission as this is required  ' +
          'to scan for wifi networks.',
        buttonNegative: 'DENY',
        buttonPositive: 'ALLOW',
      },
    );
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      WifiManager.connectToProtectedSSID('test-wifi', 'password', false)
        .then(() => console.log("connectToProtectedSSID successfully!"));
    } else {
      console.log('Permission denied');
    }
  }
```

However, I get an error for each WifiManager method

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeWifiReborn.default.connectToProtectedSSID')]
at http://192.168.1.100:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:151908:46 in onClickConnect$
```

I have found some suggestions to clean expo cache or re-install `node-modules` but that did not help.
Please help! Deadline is coming... :(

Comment: Did you find the solution for this ?
facing the same issue please anyone help us out here.